# Pupup element broken after <base href=..> tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popup

On my pages I have popup text:

```
<a id="key" href="#" rel="popover" 
data-original-title="bla" data-content='foo foo foo '>bar bar </a>
<script>
    $('#key').popover( { placement: 'top'});
</script>
```

Its was worked before I add

```
<base href="http://mydomain.ru">
```

into head.

After that popup functionality is broken, on click it show popup and redirect to base_href.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the default behaviour when clicked try;

```
<a id="key" href="#" rel="popover" onclick="javascript: return false;"
data-original-title="bla" data-content='foo foo foo '>bar bar </a>
```